# How to solve the .mat file sorting?

Tags: matlab

I have three .mat files, A.mat, B.mat and C.mat. And the content of the .mat files look like this:
![enter image description here][1]

It is in r2 = [rs2,cs2,sortedValues2] format. How can I sort rs2(e.g, 3468, 3909...) of the three 
.mat files together in increasing order, and count the number of appearance of each element of rs2?
Anyone can give me any suggestion?

Comment: How do `A`,`B` and `C` relate to `r2`? Also check out the second output from `sort`

Comment: A.mat contains a r2;B.mat contains a r2 and C.mat contains a r2. And every r2 of A, B and C looks like this format: r2 = [rs2, cs2, sortedValues2].

Comment: Is `rs2` always in ascending order in each .mat file?

Comment: no, rs2 is random order ,not ascending order

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, and `C` too large to load in memory at the same time?

Comment: so... `sortrows([A.r2;B.r2;C.r2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original

First, you're going to want load each files r2, then pull out it's rs(1, :) value into a column vector, then sort that column vector. Once you have the vector, use logical indexing to determine how many times each element repeats. Finally, attach those tow columns together to attach each element to it's corresponding count. The output vector will have duplicate rows, but I assume that won't be a problem.

```
allData = [load('A.mat',r2); load('B.mat',r2)l; load('C.mat',r2)];
colVector = allData(:, 1);
sortedVec = sort(colVector);

countVec = zeros(size(sortedVec));
for ii = 1:length(sortedVec)
    countVec(ii) = sum(sortedVec==sortedVec(ii));
end

outputVec = [sortedVec, countVec]
```

---

### Edit

Since your edited question is easy, and almost the same as your original, I'll answer it here. Most of the code is the same, you just need to get the data out of the cell array instead of the files. Like so:

```
colVector = [yourCellArray{:}];
sortedVec = sort(colVector);

countVec = zeros(size(sortedVec));
for ii = 1:length(sortedVec)
    countVec(ii) = sum(sortedVec==sortedVec(ii));
end

outputVec = [sortedVec, countVec]
```

Comment: please see the question i just edited it.The original question is for the modified one I just added.

Comment: Ok, I recommend that you restore your original question, and ask that as a separate question. It requires a separate answer, so it should be a separate question.

Comment: I cannot post another question now, have to wait 90 minutes.

Comment: Ok, here you go. It was actually simpler, so I just posted it here. It's not significantly different, so I guess it doesn't need to be a different question. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
load A
rs2_1 = r2(:,1);
clearvars r2
load B
rs2_2 = r2(:,1);
clearvars r2
load C
rs2_3 = r2(:,1);
clearvars r2

% to combine
rs2_combined = [rs2_1;rs2_2;rs2_3];
% to sort
rs2_sorted = sort(rs2_combined);
% to count for appearance
rs2_count = hist(rs2_combined, min(rs2_combined):1:max(rs2_combined));
```

---

EDIT: using cell arrays

```
% recreate your situation
R = cell(11,10);
R = cellfun(@(x) [randi(3000,50,1),ones(50,1),ones(50,1)*-.008], R,'UniformOutput', false);
% extract rs2
r = cell2mat( reshape(R, [1,1,11,10]) );
rs2 = reshape( r(:,1,:,:), [50*11*10,1] );
% do what you want
rs2_sorted = sort(rs2);
rs2_count = hist(rs2, min(rs2):1:max(rs2));
```

note - I assumed you have 50x3 arrays. If merely 50x1, then `reshape(R, [1,11,10])` and `reshape( r, [50*11*10,1] );` also works.

---

[`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) put all numbers into different bins of different values. It's equivalent to do

```
rs2_scale =  min(rs2_combined):1:max(rs2_combined);
rs2_count = zeros(1, length(rs2_scale));
for ii = 1:length(rs2_scale)
    rs2_count(ii) = sum( rs2_combined == rs2_scale(ii) );
end
```

To remove zero-count numbers -

```
rs2_count(rs2_count==0) = [];
```

Then you can calculate the probability -

```
rs2_prob = rs2_count / sum(rs2_count);
```

Validate this answer by

```
>> sum(rs2_prob)

ans =

    1.0000
```